# Ionic 2 @ionic/storage not working on Android device

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am using localstorage with ionic2 which works locally in chrome and on iphone but doesn't seem to work on Android device.

I don't really want to re-write and use Sqlite as my data fits json structure better than table structure. Any clues?

CODE

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

import { Customer } from '../pages/customer/customer.model'

@Injectable()
export class StorageService {
    constructor(private _storage: Storage) { }

    setSelectedCustomer(customer: Customer) {
        return Observable.fromPromise(this._storage.set('selectedCustomer', customer));
    }
}
```

versions:

```
"@ionic/storage": "^1.1.7",
"ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.3",
"ionic-native": "2.2.3",
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some code snippets and explain what you already tried?

Comment: There always some douches that don't have an answer for the question and just know how to click on down vote.

Comment: Thanks @Milad I was thinking it but no point saying it.

Comment: Could you precise the versions you are using and the error you encountered ?

Comment: I don't know the error, happens on some android devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a good idea to use localStorage to save important data in hybrid apps. There were too many reports about problems on android and sometime on iOS. Generally it was caused by improper data type handling. As example you're trying to save some object, but in chrome and android is could be serialized differently. So it is better to do it manually like:

```
this._storage.set('selectedCustomer', JSON.stringify(customer))
```

And then parse your object from json string using `JSON.parse`
The problem that mentioned in [this article](http://gonehybrid.com/dont-assume-localstorage-will-always-work-in-your-hybrid-app/) is still remains. So it is better to use something more robust to store user data(like SQLite)

Also, if you don't want to change the structure from json to relational tables you could try [LokiJS](https://github.com/techfort/LokiJS/)

Comment: For other NoSQL alternatives, you can look at something like Couchbase or PouchDB.  Here's a post on Couchbase + Ionic 2: https://blog.couchbase.com/2016/december/data-synchronization-with-couchbase-in-ionic-2-hybrid-mobile-apps

Answer (score 0):

i use it like this and its work fine

```
this._storage.set('selectedCustomer', JSON.stringify(customer));

this._storage.get('selectedCustomer').then((selectedCustomer) => {
    let json_selectedCustomer = JSON.parse(selectedCustomer);
    });
```

Comment: You are using a promise and I am converting to a Observable from a Promise. I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: i wanted to mention that when you are using storage as a key/value you must send the value as a string.